# How to access the ExtensionManager from an extension in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to access the `ExtensionManager` object in a NetLogo model through an extension.  The `ExtensionManager` provides access to many parts of the model that I'd like to manipulate externally, such as the PlotManager.

I can pass in Agents or Patches as arguments into the Extension, and then gain access to the `World`, `Observer`, and `Program`.  However, none of these appears to provide a path back to the `ExtensionManager`.

I have also tried to access the `ExtensionManager` from `DefaultClassManager` controlling the extension, and the `DefaultCommand` that executes the extension's code.

Below is a sample for trying to reset a plot on the interface:

```
import org.nlogo.api.*;

public class PlotExtensionManager extends DefaultClassManager{

    public void load(PrimitiveManager primitiveManager) throws ExtensionException {
        primitiveManager.addPrimitive("reset-plot", new ResetPlot());

    }

    public static class ResetPlot extends DefaultCommand{

        public Syntax getSyntax() {
            return Syntax.commandSyntax(new int[] { Syntax.StringType(), Syntax.PatchType()});
        }

        public String getAgentClassString() {
            return "OTPL";
        }

        public void perform(Argument[] args, Context context)
                throws ExtensionException, LogoException {

            // take in a plotname as a String and a single path (patch 0 0) to access the Model
            String plotName = (String) args[0].get();
            org.nlogo.agent.Patch patch = (org.nlogo.agent.Patch) args[1].get();


            org.nlogo.agent.World world = patch.world();
            org.nlogo.agent.Observer observer = world.observer();
            org.nlogo.api.Program program = world.program();

            // how to access plot on interface and gain control over it?
            // looking for access to ExtensionManager object

        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [get it from the workspace](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/5.x/src/main/org/nlogo/workspace/AbstractWorkspace.java#L116). The workspace may be acquired from the context by casting the context to a `org.nlogo.nvm.ExtensionContext` and using `context.workspace()`. So the code in Java is:

```
((ExtensionContext) context).workspace().getExtensionManager()
```

Just to warn you, none of this is in the extensions API and thus may change with future NetLogo versions.